# Do you need to encode categorical response variable in XGBoost (>= 1.5)

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

According to the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html), XGBoost has (limited) support for categorical data without individual encoding. I'm wondering if this is true for the response variable as well. I.e., if I have a categorical response variable, can I build a model without first encoding it? I'm trying to use the native interface (no scikit-learn) and build the model with the `xgb.DMatrix` class.

So right now, something like this fails since `y` is categorical

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'feature_1': ['red', 'orange', 'red', 'blue'], 'feature_2': [1, 2, 3, 7]})
X['feature_1'] = X['feature_1'].astype('category')
y = pd.Series(["small", "medium", "medium", "large"]).astype('category')
data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y, enable_categorical=True)
```

Is there a simple fix?